# Find the 90% confidence interval for the population proportion of no responses

Tags: statistics

The 2006 Florida Poll conducted by Florida International University asked, “In general,
do you think it is appropriate for state government to make laws restricting access to
abortion?” A 95% confidence interval for the population proportion of yes responses to
restricting access to abortion in a random sample of 1200 is $(0.30, 0.36)$. What can you
say about a 90% confidence interval for the population proportion of no responses to
restricting access to abortion, based on the same sample?

Ans:

We are looking at the 90% confidence interval with no given $95\%$ of yes.

$n = 1200$

$\hat\theta = \frac{0.30+0.36}{2} = 0.33$

this is a bernoulli because yes or no.

$\sqrt{\frac{\hat\theta(1-\hat\theta)}{1200}} = \sqrt{\frac{0.33 \times 0.66}{1200}} \approx 0.0135$

$CI = (1- \hat\theta) \pm z_{\frac{1+0.90}{2}} \times 0.0135 = 0.66 \pm 1.645 \times 0.0135 = (0.6377,0.68)$

answer is $(0.65, 0.69)$. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem you are accumulating rounding error.  For $\hat \theta = 0.33$, I have

$$\sqrt{\frac{\hat \theta (1 - \hat \theta)}{n}} = \sqrt{\frac{(0.33)(1 - 0.33)}{1200}} = 0.0135739.$$  Then the margin of error is $$\operatorname{ME} = (1.645)(0.0135739) = 0.022329$$ and the lower and upper confidence limits are $$(0.67 - \operatorname{ME}, 0.67 + \operatorname{ME}) = (0.647671, 0.692329),$$ which when rounded to two decimal places, agrees with the provided answer.

It is also worth noting that you inexplicably wrote $1 - 0.33 = 0.66$.  This is not true.